# C++ inline performance decrease

Tags: c++, performance, function, inline, inline-functions

I've been trying to figure out a fastest way to change vector of bytes to 64bit integer, This is a code I've used for benchmarking

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <ratio>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>

template<typename TimeT = std::chrono::milliseconds>
struct measure
{
    template<typename F, typename ...Args>
    static typename TimeT::rep execution(F func, Args&&... args)
    {
        auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast< TimeT>
                (std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start);
        return duration.count();
    }
};

inline void test()
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> bytes = { 0xd4, 0xf0, 0xfe, 0xff};

    int64_t value = 0;
    

    unsigned shift = (bytes.size() - 1) * 8;

    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.size(); i--) {
        value = value | (((int64_t)bytes[i] & 0xff) << shift);
        shift -= 8;
    }
}

int main ()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;

    uint64_t total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
    {
        auto t = measure<std::chrono::nanoseconds>::execution(test);
        total += t;
    }    

    std::cout << "Done in " << (total / 10000) << " ns." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The resault I got on my machine is about 150 NS, however when I remove the inline keyword before the function the time goes down to 50ns. So my question is - when should I avoid inlining the functions (when does it reduce performance).

I've compiled it using

```
clang++ main.cpp -o main -O3 -std=c++17
```

Comment: Isn't a `memcpy` from the vector data to an `int64_t` faster still?

Comment: Your benchmark is flawed. Both execution times range between ~50 and 150ns on my machine. Try using more iterations and be sure, your C compiler doesn't optimize away

Comment: @Bathsheba memcpy was faster, however then I have to deal with endianness

Comment: @DanielNowak: The way I deal with that is with `#ifdef`s, noting that the Unix way is the standard way when it comes to serialisation.

Comment: @JCWasmx86 I've tried with 100000000 iterations as well, It's always about 3x times without the inline (about 30ns without and 90 with)

Comment: @Bathsheba Unless the benchmarking function I have is wrong both memcpy and my method are within 1ns of each other

Comment: Please provide compiler and compiler options for you benchmark. Furthermore: Inlining is just a hint to the compiler and is mostly used for "breaking" ODR.

Comment: @knivil I've updated the question with the info you asked for

Comment: @Bathsheba: "The Unix way" of endianess? Huh? I thought *Unix* was what is running on *either* endianess... ;-)

Comment: On my machine the inline is twice faster with optimizations enabled and slightly faster when not.

Comment: @DevSolar: alright then ;-) "Unix way" -> "Typical Unix way".

Comment: @Vasilij: I'd expect O3 to collapse the `void` function to nothing. For a decent test, the function needs to return the value to the caller, and the caller consume it somehow (such as adding it to a value, and that sum being output).

Comment: @Bathsheba: What's "typical" for you, then? I've got one x86_64 and two ARM's running here. If I fire up the old A3000UX, you could add a 68k. ;-) If office machines count, add SPARC and AIX...

Comment: I used -O2. Checked in godbolt before testing. My bad was another one, I used the test as it, and it produced rather randow results. Too few iterations, too few test runs. Rewrote it a bit, added more outer loops, it now produces almost identical results.

Comment: Your loop `for (int i = 0; i < bytes.size(); i--) {` doesn't "loop", it performs one iteration. Did you mean `i++` ? Also, mixing signed and unsigned here; not cool :)

Comment: @VladFeinstein I was iterating backwards and then made a quick change but forgot to change it, all the tests were done using iterating backwards so i guess it doesnt matter

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are measuring noise.

Your code pasted into https://godbolt.org/ has no shifts; the value is pre-calculated by the compiler. That is, after I modified your `test()` to return that value, otherwise it was optimized out.